# What block will be set on pending transactions?

Tags: blockchain, pending-transactions

I have faced with different pending transactions in Ethereum. [This is one](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x508a60965f74293b448d6e5be303ff0f1d819ec55ff86e972292df46361e0615) of its strange ones which is pending after 9 days! Total amount which has sent is 1 USDT, and the fee is 0.0003 Ether.
Regarding to this sample, I need the answer of 2 questions:

1. Why such transaction is still pending after a while? The fee was not low, and the `from` account had sufficient fund.
2. Imagine when I had sent that transaction, the highest block number was 1000, and currenctly it is 2000. If the transaction becaome success now, which block number will be set on this transaction?

Answer (score 0):

1. The transaction has a gas price of 1 gWei which is super low. According to estimates at https://ethgasstation.info/calculatorTxV.php it will take 900 blocks for the block to get processed (if I interpret that right).
2. Transactions are always processed in blocks. So when a miner includes that transaction in a block the transaction gets a block number. But just including the transaction is not enough - the miner has to succeed in mining the block and the block has to become part of the canonical chain. If any of the steps fails the transaction is simply added back to the transaction pool.

Comment: Oops. It was my mistake about the Gas. I had looked at Max Txn Cost/Fee. You are right, the gas was too low and it is acceptable that transaction is still pendnig. Also thank for the answer 2